AC, Is it normal? The outside wind enters the house through the AC fan
I got a renovated house last summer, so the air-conditioner was new product. But when I turned on at first, it blowed so hot air. During the summer, I'd always turned on turbo mode 24hours, yet still warm air has blowed. 
After the summer, I found out that the wind has be still blowing from outside even though the air-conditioner was off. So, I thought there was an installation error.
At first, I blocked all gaps around between the air-conditioner and the wall. The blowing was a little decreased but still blowing. After then, I blocked the whole holes like fan holes, filter holes and front main-body holes. Only then, the wind blowing had stoped.
*** Now, Question ! ***

Is it normal for air to come in from outside through the air conditioner fan even though the air conditioner is off? When it's windy outside, the wind from outside gets stronger. Of course, the wind gets weaker on non-wind days. Which do you think is the problem, wrong installation or something wrong with the product?

How can I solve this problem? I'm trying to reinstall by myself, or should I call a professional? (How much do you think?)



look up the model number and post it here

Many ACs have a '"ventilated" setting that opens a door to bring in a small amount of fresh air. Yours could be open or not sealing well.

It looks like you have multiple accounts. Please use the Contact Us form to request a merge so your new account owns this question
